# Java Process Builder IO Exception - won't run program

Tags: java, process, processbuilder

Here is my code and I am not sure why the following error is coming up:

```
 Opening firefox at Sun Oct 28 21:45:27 EDT 2012
 java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "firefox.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

public static void open(String app) {
        try {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date now = calendar.getTime();
            System.out.println("Opening " + app + " at " + now);
            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(app+".exe");
            builder.start();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does _"The system cannot find the file specified"_ mean to you?

Comment: I inputted "firefox". I tried to run firefox from the command prompt and it worked. Why wouldn't it here?

Comment: It looks like the application can't be found.  If the application does not exist in the current system path, you need to supply the path to the executable.  Try something like `System.out.println(new File(app + ".exe").exists());` and see if the file exists within the location you are running from (or as specified by the path supplied with the `app` String)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify the full path to the Firefox executable.

Comment: There has to be a simpler way of doing that than actually specifying every possible file path.. How can I do this efficiently?

Comment: unfortunately it seems that ProcessBuilder ignores the system default paths.

Comment: is there an argument I can add to not ignore them?

Comment: @phileaton - you're not using a shell. There's no such thing as a "search path". You have to specify where the file is you wish to execute.